# check multidimensional array exists another multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have toe different  multidimensional array  following :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

)
```

I want to check small multidimensional array exists in bigger array. Any suggestion please.
I am using

```
$diff = Hash::diff(samllarray, $bigger array);
```

of cakephp and its result is

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

)
```

but  in result I want only 3rd key  but its also given me 2rd key see above

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @Andrew How should you be able to tell with `count()` if a subArray exists in another array?!

Comment: what is the expected result for your example?

Comment: @Rizier123 Oh, I misunderstood the question. I though OP wanted to check if an array is multidimensional.

Comment: @Andrew If then you can't tell with count() if it is multidimensional.

Comment: @Rizier123 Of course you can. Count the array twice. Once using `count` without an argument and secondly using `count` with the `COUNT_RECURSIVE` argument. If they're equal, it's not multidimensioanl. If they're not, it is. For example `count($array) == count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE)`

Comment: if array keys value is array, its ok. Compare these values to see your answer. Are they the same or not.

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with CakePHP. I really don't get it why so many people tag random php and js problems with *CakePHP*. I've updated the question with a better matching tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is_array()` to see if a variable is an array.

```
$arrs = array(
    0 => "big array",
    1 => "big array",
    3 => array(
        0 => "nested array",
        1 => "nested array"
    )
);

foreach ($arrs as $key=>$value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        echo "we've got an array at index {$key}";
    }
}
```